# What folder on Mac is writeable without admin access but readable by all users?

Tags: macos, security

I'm looking for a place to save my app's license file. I want it in a location that's accessible by all users so if one user on the machine activates the app, the app is also activated for every other user. However, I don't want to require elevation to write to this location.

On Windows, I use C:\Users\Public. Is there an equivalent on OS X?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any directory you own publicly accessible by allowing it with chmod. For instance:

```
mkdir ~/Public
chmod 755 ~/Public
```

will create and make world-readable the directory /Users/YourName/Public

Comment: Great - this worked. I created /Users/Shared/MyApp and then changed the permissions on it. Thanks!